# Left Join, Counting with PHP & MySQL for simple blog script

Tags: mysql, left-join

I think I have reached my current limits with Left Joins. Currently I have the following MySQL query which is working fine:

```
SELECT blog.id, blog.title, blog.post, blog.date, blog.time,
       count(blog_comment.b_id) CommCount
FROM blog 
LEFT JOIN blog_comment ON blog.id = blog_comment.b_id
GROUP BY blog.id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT $start_blog, $blog_per_page
```

This will display a list of blog posts and display the number of comments each post has, nice and simple.

For the admin panel I want to display the Blog Posts followed by the number of comments on each post and then a new field which displays the number of pending comments.

The pending comments are stored in blog_comment.pending (1 for pending, 0 for not pending)

I just can't seem to get my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT blog.id, blog.title, blog.post, blog.date, blog.time, 
       count(blog_comment.b_id) CommCount,
       sum(blog_comment.pending) PendingComments
FROM blog 
LEFT JOIN blog_comment ON blog.id = blog_comment.b_id 
GROUP by blog.id 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_blog , $blog_per_page
```

Sum will simply add up the number of **pending** flags...

Comment: Thank you so much, that was just the ticket for what I was after.